# Multiple boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot

I have gene expression data as follows:

```
       Control            Treatment
        L1    L2          L1   L2      
 g1   10.5    12          13   14  
 g2    11     13          10.5 12  
 g3    10     9           11   10   
 g4    9      8           6     5 
 g5    16     4           4     6
 g6    11     12          5     4
 g7    10     6           13    12 
 g8    5      4           12    12  
 g9    11     12          10    11.5   
 g10   8.9    7.8         7.6   5.8
```

where the rows represent the genes and there are two conditions "control" and "treatment" which is further subdivided into "L1", "L2" and "L1" and "L2" respectively.

I would like to make a boxplot of these expression values in the following way and represent them as a boxplot ??

[image: Boxplot]

Comment: first prepare data in melted for with variables genotype, control_Treatment, L1L2, value...(hint `reshape2` package, `melt()` then we will go further

Comment: @ Ananta: I know to reshape it when I have two conditions but am not sure how it works here.

Comment: Add a column to each data frame identifying control/treatment, then rbind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
1   g1 10.5 12.0 13.0 14.0
2   g2 11.0 13.0 10.5 12.0
3   g3 10.0  9.0 11.0 10.0
4   g4  9.0  8.0  6.0  5.0
5   g5 16.0  4.0  4.0  6.0
6   g6 11.0 12.0  5.0  4.0
7   g7 10.0  6.0 13.0 12.0
8   g8  5.0  4.0 12.0 12.0
9   g9 11.0 12.0 10.0 11.5
10 g10  8.9  7.8  7.6  5.8


x.m<-melt(x, id.var="V1")
x.m$control<-ifelse(x.m$variable %in% c("V2", "V3"), "Control","Treatment")
x.m$L<-ifelse(x.m$variable %in% c("V2", "V4"), "L1","L2")

ggplot(x.m, aes(x=L,y=value,  fill=control))+geom_boxplot()
```